# py.test and norecursedirs granuarity

Tags: python, pytest

I have these directories:

```
./Tools
./ook/Tools.
```

I have added `Tools` to the `norecursedirs` options of py.test in `setup.cfg`. As expected, when py.test gathers tests, `./Tools` is not explored.  However, neither is `./ook/Tools` and this is a problem as I *want* this one.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of norecursedirs is a glob pattern and to make it match on the full path your pattern must include a / character.  Unfortunately the full path this is matched against is an absolute path so if you only want the base Tools you will have to include the parent directory name:

```
$ find root/
root/
root/Tools
root/Tools/test_foo.py
root/Tools/__init__.py
root/setup.cfg
root/ook
root/ook/Tools
root/ook/Tools/test_foo.py
root/ook/__init__.py
$ cat root/setup.cfg
[pytest]
norecursedirs = root/Tools
$ py.test --collectonly root/
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- pytest-2.2.1
collected 1 items 
<Module 'root/ook/Tools/test_foo.py'>
  <Function 'test_foo'>

===============================  in 0.01 seconds ===============================
```